# Collections.sort() on Generic Data Structure not working

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have been asked to create a `toArray` method which should return an Iterator or array, respectively, with elements sorted by their “add” counts (values in the HashMap) in ascending order.

However, I am getting the following error message and don't know how to fix it:

> The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Set<Map.Entry<T,Integer>>, new Comparator<Map.Entry<T,Integer>>(){})

So it seems like I have to override or create the sort method. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

```
public class OccurenceSet<T> implements Set<T>{

     private HashMap<T,Integer> data;

     public OccurenceSet(){
         this.data = new HashMap<T,Integer>();
     }

     @Override
     public Object[] toArray() {

         Set<Map.Entry<T,Integer>> dataSet = data.entrySet();
         ArrayList<Map.Entry<T,Integer>> dataList = new ArrayList<>(dataSet);
         Collections.sort(dataSet, new Comparator<Map.Entry<T,Integer>>() {
              @Override
              public int compare(Map.Entry<T,Integer> o1, Map.Entry<T, Integer> o2) {
                  return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
              }
          });

      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Collections.sort sorts Lists, not Sets. General Sets don't have an order.

Comment: try Collections.sort(dataList...

Answer (score 2):

**HashMap is not meant to keep entries in sorted order, but if you have to sort HashMap based upon keys or values, you can do that in Java.**

1. Get all entries by calling entrySet() method of Map
2. Create a custom Comparator to sort entries based upon values.
3. Convert entry set to list.
4. Sort entry list by using Collections.sort() method by passing your value comparator
5. Create a LinkedHashMap by adding entries in sorted order.

Answer (score 2):

> "The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Set>, new Comparator>(){})"

You are getting this exception because `Collections#sort` method can only accept **`List<T>`** not a **Set**

More Information here : [Collections#sort Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))